# Even when the week starts out badly, things can get better!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Monday: My father threatened to disinherit me.
Tuesday: I wasn't picked for my team
Wednesday: I almost got married to the wrong girl.
Thursday: I signed on with a new team.
Friday: I adopted a 5-year-old boy.
Saturday: I inherited a bunch of money from an unknown relative.
Sunday: I finally got married—to the absent-minded girl of my dreams.

> Do you know who I am?

Comment: _The following Monday_: I just pray for a boring week.

Comment: @Phylyp And instead, your twin sister comes to visit for the worst holiday gathering in the history of mankind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are

> Adam Sandler

Monday: My father threatened to disinherit me.

> Billy Madison

Tuesday: I got cut from the team. [EDIT: Oops, I mean I wasn't picked for the team]

> Happy Gilmore

Wednesday: I almost got married to the wrong girl.

> The Wedding Singer

Thursday: I signed on with a new team.

> The Waterboy

Friday: I adopted a 5-year-old boy.

> Big Daddy

Saturday: I inherited a bunch of money from an unknown relative.

> Mr. Deeds

Sunday: I finally got married—to the absent-minded girl of my dreams.

> 50 First Dates

Comment: It would be amusing if the character played by your answer was actually the same person across all of your explanations for each clue :-) Reminiscent of how fans have posited that some Disney animated films inhabit a shared universe.

Comment: @Phylyp ...like [this one](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WdGEMIbWiq0/maxresdefault.jpg)?